# Stop x-axis labels from shrinking the plot in Matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm, seaborn

I'm trying to make a bar graph with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

test = {'names':['a','b','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789012345678901234567890'], 'values':[1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(test)

plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = False
ax = sns.barplot(x='names', y='values', data=df)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

But I get the following error because the long value in 'names' as a label on the x-axis is making the image shrink until the bottom is above the top.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Adam/.PyCharm2018.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 11, in <module>
    plt.show()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 253, in show
    return _show(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.3\helpers\pycharm_matplotlib_backend\backend_interagg.py", line 25, in __call__
    manager.show(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.3\helpers\pycharm_matplotlib_backend\backend_interagg.py", line 107, in show
    self.canvas.show()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.3\helpers\pycharm_matplotlib_backend\backend_interagg.py", line 62, in show
    self.figure.tight_layout()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2276, in tight_layout
    self.subplots_adjust(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2088, in subplots_adjust
    self.subplotpars.update(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 245, in update
    raise ValueError('bottom cannot be >= top')
ValueError: bottom cannot be >= top
```

Here is what it looks like if I reduce the length of that name slightly:
[image]

How can I get it to expand the figure to fit the label instead of shrinking the axes?

Comment: probably this answer is one same lines and might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708888/valueerror-when-using-matplotlib-tight-layout

Comment: omg... it's the PyCharm internal backend that calls `tight_layout`... no comment on that, except... maybe not to use pycharm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to create the `Axes` instance yourself as *axes*, not as subplot. Then `tight_layout()` has no effect, even if it's called internally. You can then pass the `Axes` with the `ax` keyword to `sns.barplot`. The problem now is that if you call `plt.show()` the label may be cut off, but if you call `savefig` with `bbox_inches='tight'`, the figure size will be extended to contain both the figure and all labels:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

test = {'names':['a','b','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789012345678901234567890'], 'values':[1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(test)

#plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = False
ax = sns.barplot(x='names', y='values', data=df, ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
#plt.show()
fig.savefig('long_label.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

PROCLAIMER: I don't have `pycharm`, so there goes the assumption in this code, that `matplotlib` behaves the same with and without `pycharm`. Anyway, for me the outcome looks like this:

[image: result of above code]

Comment: Great workaround!  I was having issues with getting `imshow()` in a subplots grid to have the images take up the full width of the larger figure, when the `xlabel` exceeded a certain length.  This fixed it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this in an interactive backend I didn't find any other way than manually adjust the figure size. This is what I get using the `qt5agg` backend:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x='names', y='values', data=df)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
ax.figure.set_size_inches(5, 8)  # manually adjust figure size
plt.tight_layout()  # automatically adjust elements inside the figure
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that pycharm's scientific mode might be doing some magic that prevents this to work so you might need to deactivate it or just run the script outside pycharm.