# How to plot oversize ticks properly?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

When the text label of [a tick](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html) is too long, often time we need to rotate it to prevent overlapping of texts. The issue I am having here is that matplotlib will display only a portion of it when it is longer than the size of the graph.

**1. Is there a way to extend the margin of the bottom of the graph so that it fits all the text?**

**2. If horizontal is more preferable, is there a way to put text into two or more lines so they don't overlap?**

Here is an example that cutting off the text:
[image]

I tried to [adjust the size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib) with

```
plt.figure(figsize=(50,50))
```

but it only results in a proportional increase of every element in the graph.

I tried to adjust the [margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042192/reduce-left-and-right-margins-in-matplotlib-plot) with

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

but it seems to trade off with the graph content. Finally, thought of [adjusting the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965743/how-can-i-set-the-aspect-ratio-in-matplotlib), but it seems to related to the content of the graph only.

I am currently using matplotlib 2.2.2 and
you may reproduce the graph above with the following code ([original](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

# plt.figure(figsize=(500,20))

p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, yerr=menStd)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, womenMeans, width,
             bottom=menMeans, yerr=womenStd)

plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
# plt.xticks(ind, ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))

plt.xticks(ind, ('It shows up perfectly fine in Jupyter Notebook', 'how can I adjust "some setting" so that I can see all these?', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
plt.tick_params(labelrotation=90)
# plt.savefig('Example.jpeg')

# plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Look into axes position and bounds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop x-axis labels from shrinking the plot in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461980/stop-x-axis-labels-from-shrinking-the-plot-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
```

to get more space under the plot. The default value is 0.1.

Note that with the default figure size, I could not increase the space so that the complete (very long) text is visible. If you define a figure size, it should be possible, though.